# Can't access attributes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, class-visibility

When I run this code, I get an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'test'"

```
class BaseClass:
    def __new__(self, number):
        self.test = 1

class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    pass

instance = InheritedClass(1)
print(instance.test)
```

Can someone explain to me what exactly gets inherited from the base? There seems to be a difference between Python 2 and 3, because if I put "test" in the attribute field of the Baseclass I can access it in Python 2, but not in 3.

Comment: I don't think that this is discussed in the duplicate answer. The difference in behaviour between Python 2 and 3 is that `__new__()` exists only for new-style classes, i.e. those that are explicitly inherited from `object`. In your code `__new__()` is not even called in Python 2. In Python 3 it is called, but there is no instance because `__new__()` returns `None` - `__new__()` should return the instance. The answers in the duplicate address this latter point in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "**new**"  to "**init**"

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.test = 1

class InheritedClass(BaseClass):
    pass

instance = InheritedClass(1)
print(instance.test)
```

Comment: OP is seeking an explanation, not just code that works.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between **new** and **init**.
To access fields like this you should call them in init.

Comment: OP is seeking an explanation, not just code that works.